# control robot via Jacobian inverse?

Tags: ros, inverse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi . how can i control robot via Jacobian inverse ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277309/control-robot-via-jacobian-inverse-?/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2017-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[here](https://github.com/UTNuclearRoboticsPublic/jog_arm) is an example.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1